# How to disable paste action in SWT Text

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, swt, jface

I have an SWT Text and i dont want any special characters to be entered , but only digits and numbers. So i have used the verify lister for the text :

```
text.addVerifyListener(new VerifyListener()
    {

        @Override
        public void verifyText(VerifyEvent event) 
        {
            char eachChar = (Character)event.character;

            if(Character.isLetterOrDigit(eachChar))
            {
                event.doit = true;
            }
                            else
                            {
                                   event.doit = false;
                            }

        }


    });
```

So now i'll not be able to enter special characters.

1) How do i enable paste of a text inside the Text ?

2) And when i copy a text containing special characters from outside and paste it in the Text , it should not get pasted How do i restrict this ?

Please suggest me on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> > 1) How do i enable paste of a text inside the Text ?

Paste will be enabled by default for SWT text. You no need to enable explicitly.

> > 2) And when i copy a text containing special characters from outside and paste it in the Text , it should not get pasted How do i restrict this ?

"event.text" will give you the text you enter/paste to the SWT text. Validate this event.text with your regular expression (or with your isLetterOrDigit() by reading the event.text as character)